# Can Harm reduce you to below 1 HP if you fail the save?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, hit-points

The spell description for [Harm](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/harm.htm) says:

> Harm charges a subject with negative energy that deals 10 points of
>   damage per caster level (to a maximum of 150 points at 15th level). If
>   the creature successfully saves, harm deals half this amount, but it
>   cannot reduce the target’s hit points to less than 1.

As written, it appears that the save the spell cannot reduce you below 1 hit point if you make the save. Is this also the case of if you fail the save? Because if not this seems like it's a save or die spell (which I know 3.5 is rife with, just want to know if this is another).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### *Harm* isn't intended to work as an instant kill.

While it's ambiguously worded, the D&D 3.5 FAQ p.83 clarifies the design intent of the spell. *Harm* cannot reduce you below 1 hit point even if you fail your save.

> Q: The *harm* spell deals 10 points of damage per caster level (to a maximum of 150 points at 15th level) and cannot take a target's hit points to less than 1. If the target creature makes a successful saving throw, the damage is reduced by half, but the spell still cannot reduce the target's hit points to less than 1. [...]
>
> A: Technically, that's right. [...]

This makes sense if you consider the D&D 3.0 version of the spell, which reduced you to 1d4 hit points no matter the total. D&D 3.5's method instituted a damage cap but retained the spell's inability to work as an instant kill.

Consider also that it says "but it cannot reduce", rather than "*and* it cannot reduce", suggesting that this clause is not an additional benefit of passing a save.

However, as the FAQ notes, you can happen to die from the little-used Massive Damage rule, which requires a DC 15 Fortitude save any time you take 50 damage from a single source. The FAQ recommends ignoring massive damage from *harm* as a house rule, since *harm* is not intended to be an instant kill. Every D&D 3.5 group I've played in has ignored the Massive Damage rule in general.